# PHP upload script not working in Firefox but in Chrome

Tags: php, firefox, google-chrome, file-upload

I am trying to use this PHP script to check extension of file while upload. The problem is that it works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox it is always returning false even when the extension is correct and so "Invalid File" is being echoed always.

```
    $allowedExts = array("mp3", "wma", "wav", "ogg", "aac", "aiff", "amr", "ra");
    $arr = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($arr);

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wma")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/wav")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/ogg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/aac")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/aiff")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/amr")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/ra"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
       .
       .
       .
       .
      }
    else
      {
      echo "Invalid file";
      }
```

Can anyone please tell what is the problem in the if section that it's not working in Firefox?

Comment: You should do a <?php var_dump($_FILES["file"]["type"]); die(); ?> and see what is being output in the different browsers.

Comment: Try checking the MIME type instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: As an aside, you should use `in_array` for the file types as well as extensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the file type has audio/type name and your matching it to just the type.

Try using in_array function and remove the audio/ using preg_replace

```
$allowedExts = array("mp3", "wma", "wav", "ogg", "aac", "aiff", "amr", "ra");
$allowedSize = 20000000;
$currentType = preg_replace('/(.*)(/)/','',$_FILES['file']['type']);
$currentSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];

if( in_array($currentType,$allowedExts) && $currentSize < $allowedSize ) 
{
    // DO UPLOAD 
    // REFER TO http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php
}
else
{
    // ERROR UPLOADING FILE
}
```

Comment: It is now giving error... and isn't working on Chrome anymore..Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier

Comment: It is now giving error... and isn't working on Chrome anymore.

        Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier

Answer (score 0):

PHP works the same regardless of the browser.

You need to look at your HTML code.

That is where the problem lies.